# MvvmCross error dialog in android 7.0

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working with Xamarin.Android and use MvvmCross framework to development. My project working fine on android version bellow android 7 but when running on android 7 it has a problem: When I running app, it auto display a white dialog with empty message and just have a button "OK". I checked this bug and find that extend MvxAppcompatActivity is reason of issue. I want to fix this bug. Please help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks your solution. It has working.

Comment: Edited my suggestion comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your dialog with empty message, shows you an error message, but because of incorrect styles configuration, it looks like empty. 
I had similiar problem, with 7 version of android with dialogs. 
Fixed this problem by setting accentColor in your application style theme.